# How to create Always Encrypted Certificate for specific time period?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, encryption, always-encrypted

I have configured Always Encrypted on a custom database using SQL Server 2016. By default, it creates the certificate with a validity of one year.

Is there any workaround to create this certificate for two or three years at the very beginning stage?

I don't want to rotate the key every year in our production environment rather create the certificate at least for two or three years.

Experts advise please.

Comment: You don't have to use the ''MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE'' . There are other options including custom provider. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-column-master-key-transact-sql) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider). If you use Azure key vault you can set your own expiration date. http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/expiry-notification-for-azure-key-vault-keys-and-secrets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this first came out I had a blog post on this, creating the certificate via Powershell: https://justdaveinfo.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/always-on-encrypted-generating-certificates-and-column-encryption-key-encrypted_value/

Checking the documentation for the Powershell cmdlet New-SelfSignedCertificate you should be able to use "-NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(24)"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps